# Moodle PHPUnit test message provider problem

Tags: automated-tests, phpunit, moodle

I made a PHPUnit test for my moodle plugin
But always get this error.
It suppose that for every transaction a message sent to the user
In live website, this function works fine but not in the PHPUnit test?

How to enable this message provider in the test code?

Debugging: Attempt to send msg from a provider enrol_wallet/wallet_transaction that is inactive or not allowed for the user id=148000

- line 225 of /lib/messagelib.php: call to debugging()
- line 80 of /enrol/wallet/classes/notifications.php: call to message_send()
- line 144 of /enrol/wallet/classes/transactions.php: call to enrol_wallet\notifications::transaction_notify()
- line 64 of /enrol/wallet/tests/transactions_test.php: call to enrol_wallet\transactions::debit()
- line 1548 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php: call to enrol_wallet\transactions_test->test_credit_debit()
- line 1154 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php: call to PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runTest()
- line 80 of /lib/phpunit/classes/advanced_testcase.php: call to PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runBare()
- line 728 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php: call to advanced_testcase->runBare()
- line 904 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php: call to PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run()
- line 675 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php: call to PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run()
- line 675 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php: call to PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run()
- line 675 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php: call to PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run()
- line 661 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php: call to PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run()
- line 144 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php: call to PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->run()
- line 97 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php: call to PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run()
- line 98 of /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit: call to PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
- line 122 of /vendor/bin/phpunit: call to include()

When I used:

```
message_get_providers_from_db('enrol_wallet');
```

or

```
message_get_providers_from_file('enrol_wallet');
```

both indicated that the provider existed and active

but when I use:

```
message_get_providers_for_user($user->id);
```

The provider not exist in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is the enrol plugin itself isn't enabled

So the message provider with the plugin will not work in PHPUnit testunless the plugin enabled first.

so I enabled it first before taking action using the code and add it to the test at the beginning:

```
global $CFG;
if (!enrol_is_enabled('wallet')) {
    $class = \core_plugin_manager::resolve_plugininfo_class('enrol');
    // This method isn't exist in 3.11.
    if (method_exists($class, 'enable_plugin')) {
        $class::enable_plugin('wallet', true);
    } else {
        $plugins = [];
        if (!empty($CFG->enrol_plugins_enabled)) {
            $plugins = array_flip(explode(',', $CFG->enrol_plugins_enabled));
        }
        if (!array_key_exists('wallet', $plugins)) {
            $plugins['wallet'] = 'wallet';
            $new = implode(',', array_flip($plugins));
            add_to_config_log('enrol_plugins_enabled', false, true, 'wallet');
            set_config('enrol_plugins_enabled', $new);
            // Reset caches.
            \core_plugin_manager::reset_caches();
            // Resets all enrol caches.
            $syscontext = \context_system::instance();
            $syscontext->mark_dirty();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited it, I hope it is clearer now